# Alfresco webscript post parameters from client sidejavascript file?

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

I have created webscripts for creating new start workflow using javascript,I want to post the parameter value to webscripts from client side java script is this possible?

Comment: Add them to the URL you request as normal?

Answer (score 1):

Use the OOTB Alfresco's JS function which can send your Object via the requests
`Alfresco.util.Ajax.request(
         {
            url: "your URL",
            method: Alfresco.util.Ajax.POST,
            dataObj: YOUR_OBJECT,
            requestContentType: Alfresco.util.Ajax.JSON,
            successCallback:
            {
               fn: successHandler,
               scope: this
            },
            failureCallback:
            {
               fn: failureHandler,
               scope: this
            }
         });`

Comment: Yes i  am able to send values to webscripts how can i receive the webscripts ? and how can i populated values in workflow  form cloud you help me with reference